# Dynamic email body shows only in developer mode and only if the sender email configured

Tags: gmail, amp-html, amp-email

When sending email message with three bodies, Text, HTML and AMP, Gmail does not display the AMP version unless the the Dynamic email in settings is marked, and the sender email address is specified.

[image]

According to  this article: https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2019/06/dynamic-email-in-gmail-becoming-GA.html Google made AMP generally available on July 2nd, which means I do not have to have a special setting. When I have the sender email configured, I can see the AMP version. When I remove it, I can only see HTML version, which does not seem like "general availability".

Any help is much appreciated.

UPDATE: 
See  response from Google Support. They are claiming that "you do not need to submit form anymore"
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow the steps outlined in [Register with Google](https://developers.google.com/gmail/ampemail/register) in order for your sender email to be enabled for sending AMP emails to all Gmail users.

The setting from your screenshot allows you to bypass this on your own account and is only used for testing and debugging your emails.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not accurate. We submitted for registration with Google two months ago, and never heard from them. After about 4 weeks, we opened a support ticket, but were told by Google that AMP has "general availability" which does not require registration anymore. However, it is still not working,.

Comment: General availability only refers to G Suite users being able to receive these emails (originally, it was only available to Gmail users). Registration is still required for all email senders.

Comment: we have registered the sending  domain, sent a test email to their email address, etc. After a month of waiting from Google, we filed a ticket, and they said that "general availability" means no need for registration. In any case, we  have submitted  a registration form about two months ago. Is your information official? Is there a reference  you can share?

Comment: The link in my answer is the official documentation. Where did you open the support ticket you mentioned? I strongly recommend filing for registration again if you haven't received confirmation you're registered.

Comment: I opened the support with Google using our Google Apps support line, and it took a week for the support person to realize what I was asking about.